# Разбиение таблицы

Tags: python, pandas

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить метод, который "длинную" табличку размерности, например, 20х3, разбивает на 2 подтабличек 10x3, т.е. примерно как-то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(20, 3))) #исходный датафрейм

def data_separator_2(data):
    h = data.shape[0]
    data1 = data[0:int(h/2)]
    data2 = data[int(h/2):h]
            
    data_modified = pd.merge(data1, data2)

    return data_modified

data_separator_2(df)
```

Вызов функции просто выдает названия стобцов.

При этом хотелось бы сохранить сквозную нумерацию элементов и предусмотреть случай нечетной размерности получаемой таблички. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: а что, слайс не работает `df1 = df[:10]`

Comment: ну не догадался

Comment: но все равно как присобачить нижнюю часть таблицы правее

Comment: скажите, какие принципиальные соображения мешают вам привести вид фрейма до и после? я, например, не понимаю, что должно получится в результате

Comment: скажите, какие принципиальные соображения мешают вам привести вид фрейма до и после? я, например, не понимаю, что должно получится в результате

Comment: пока я писал свой ответ, меня опередили. во-первых, надо использовать локаторы для получения частей исходного фрейма, а не срезы, иначе вы получите совсем не то, что ожидали. во вторых - вместо merge - concat с указанием оси и сбросом индексов. Впрочем, в ответе все очевидно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с `concat()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(20, 3)))  # исходный датафрейм
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:(df.shape[0] // 2)].reset_index(drop=True), df.iloc[(df.shape[0] // 2):].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1,
               ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  5  2  1  8  6  8
1  9  2  3  0  1  5
2  5  8  5  4  0  6
3  8  2  9  6  2  1
4  3  8  2  9  6  5
5  8  8  1  4  8  1
6  9  7  3  1  2  4
7  0  9  3  5  0  3
8  2  6  1  4  5  7
9  7  3  9  0  6  9
```